# OnItemClick to play audio didn't work

Tags: android, audio, media-player, onclicklistener

I need to make an application that playing audio from raw folder.
I set OnClickListener for image  but it didn't work.

this is my code:

```
public class DetailInko extends Activity {
DBHelper dbHelper;
private TextView hangeul, romanisasi, artiIndo, keterangan;
String txAud;
private ImageView Audio;
Button bck;

public DetailInko() {
}

public void openDB() {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    dbHelper.open();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_inko);
    hangeul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hangeul);
    romanisasi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.romanisasi);
    artiIndo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artiIndonesia);
    keterangan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artiPlus);
    Audio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonSound);
    bck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
```

//getdata from previous activity, it already work well

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        hangeul.setText(b.getString("Kor"));
        romanisasi.setText(b.getString("Rom"));
        artiIndo.setText(b.getString("Indo"));
        keterangan.setText(b.getString("Ket"));
        txAud = b.getString("Audio").replaceAll(".WAV", ""); // I'm not sure about this code
    }

    final MediaPlayer mp;
    int i;
```

//get the audio from raw folder and I don't know if this code could get the .wav file from folder raw. the sound didn't play

```
    i = getResources().getIdentifier(txAud, "raw", getPackageName());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(DetailInko.this, i);

    onCLick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp != null){
                mp.start();
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Could somebody solved this problem? Thank you-

Comment: When you click the imageView does it enter the code you want to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
just Put your file in res/raw folder and use
```

public void onClick(View v) {

```
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        } else{

        try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Comment: what if I want to replaceAll the data string to .wav from raw folder. is that possible?

Comment: Yes media player support .wav files also, but your .wav file should be in properly converted format, with any audio converter